# Docker publishing ports to multiple IPs

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

If I have a host with two IPs, say 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3 and I run a container like this:

```
docker run -p 192.168.0.3:80:80 some_container
```

and then I run another container like this:

```
docker run -p 80:80 some_other_container
```

Then what happens?

A) Second command fails with "address already in use" OR
B) some_other_container has its port 80 exposed on 192.168.0.2 while some_container has its port 80 exposed on 192.168.0.3 ?

If it's A) then how can I make this work in such a way that "some_container" always has its port 80 exposed on 192.168.0.3 and "some_other_container" which is started with "-p" (cannot specify IP) always exposes its ports on 192.168.0.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is easy enough to answer with a quick test:

```
$ docker run -itd -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 nginx
acdf03bd196d2241d4f776ff701eab6222cc80bfb1b4dd06bc65af0a3625e602
$ docker run -itd -p 80:80 nginx
b75938101d9c8a28b0d7d220b0046a4f8884fb82e9bc337c65d48a214bc3e54f
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint lonely_kirch (c144b82f83c7ab1c527c25d9a6807d37069a7382181f9bf98bb1b1cd93976313): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use.
```

Unless you want to rewrite the linux network stack (not recommended), I believe your options are to either pass the IP to your second run command, pass a default IP to the docker daemon (`dockerd -ip 192.168.0.2`), or pick a different port.

Comment: Thanks, I found about the option of passing an IP to the docker daemon and that's what I am going to do. The only problem (which I didn't mention in the original question) is that I also want to be able to change these IPs without recreating the containers. Docker will be running inside a VM. I have to be able to take a snapshot of the VM and create a new one from the snapshot with exactly the same Docker configuration. I can change the docker daemon binding IP before I start the second VM but I haven't been able to find a way how to change the binding IP of an existing container...

Comment: That's a pretty unique problem, and don't think there's an easy solution to that. Docker isn't magic, when you change IP on the box, everything currently bound on that IP is likely to have problem, pretty sure Docker will be included in that list. Think you'll be best off either bouncing the containers (if not the entire daemon), or use a proxy that you can relay all traffic through so it can listen on all interfaces.